# Why doesn't the type f (f b c) (f (f a b) (f a c)) match (.)?

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, function-composition, hoogle

I have just formulated the type of `(.)`, generalized, as far as I can tell, however, upon typing it into [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=f%20(f%20b%20c)%20(f%20(f%20a%20b)%20(f%20a%20c))&start=21), I received no results.

I'd have expected

```
(.) :: (->) ((->) b c) ((->) ((->) a b) ((->) a c))
     ~ (b -> c) -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> c))
     ~ (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

to match

```
thistype ~ f (f b c) (f (f a b) (f a c))
```

Comment: At a guess, hoogle does not allow `f` to specialise to `->`. What if you had a type family `X` such that `X a b c` was the type of `(.)`. Then you can’t really expect hoogle to match `f a b c` with `(.)` merely because `X` could be so defined.

Comment: @DanRobertson Well, I'd say the reason that wouldn't work is because you aren't allowed to say `f ~ X` anyway. You *are* allowed to say `f ~ (->)`. Indeed, if I look up [`:: a -> f a`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3A%3A+a+->+f+a), I get the usual suspects, plus a ton of results for various specializations of `f`, like `f ~ Identity` or `f ~ parsec:Consumed`. You are probably correct in saying that Hoogle doesn't like to specialize type constructors to `(->)`, but the rationale given doesn't seem right.

Comment: Why is `f ~ X` not allowed? Do you mean that in `f ~ (->)`, `(->)` is a type constructor but `X` being a type family does not count? I think the real answer anyway is that hoogle treats functions in a special way so that searches can reorder arguments. Note that `f b c -> f a b -> f a c` will find `(.)` for categories, but still not specialised to functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technical answer is that Hoogle splits the search into arguments and return types on the outer `(->)` parts, and then searches for each part individually, before combining the results. The outer `(->)` is treated very specially, in particular it's happy to reorder arguments.

The more fundamental reason why Hoogle works this way is that it's a search engine, not a unification engine. If you were searching for the above, and got back `(.)`, would that have answered your question? My guess is probably not. My favourite example is that searching for `"a -> [(a,b)] -> b"` should return `lookup`, even though it doesn't unify.

Comment: Why should that return `lookup`?

Comment: That type is "search through an associative list". Lookup is the function that does it. Therefore one should find the other, ideally.